# In what order we have to learn web languages?

Tags: programming-languages

Can anyone please tell me, in what order we've to learn languages?

```
1.(X)HTML
2.CSS
3.JS, HTML DOM, jQuery (client-side)
4.SQL
5.PHP & MySQL (server-side)
6.Ajax
```

Am I correct? Is it good to learn "jQuery" before learning PHP & MySQL, SQL, Ajax?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of career you are headed for or what projects you are working on?  Of course, this list will vary for everyone.  I learned HTML and a backend system long long long before learning CSS or Javascript or SQL... If I was starting now to do what I do today I would learn HTML, CSS and Javascript really well and blindly use the few backend hook APIs I need (for a while at least)...  For learning JS, I'd recommend starting with a clean library like jQuery, though as others mentioned, it is not a language-- but it helps you write good JS.

Comment: Definitely learn JavaScript before jQuery and AJAX, since jQuery is a JavaScript library and you'll probably be using jQuery with AJAX.

Answer (score 13):

1. (X)HTML
2. CSS
3. (any server side language you want)
4. (whatever database language you want)
5. JavaScript
6. (any javascript library you want)

To summarize. First learn structure, then learn style, then learn the backend languages (and their databases) and then learn JS and whatever library you want with it.

Comment: As a little extra for anyone else who is new to web-dev and might be confused by the details of what #3,#4, and #6 are (@Ólafur Waage -  great answer btw)

#3 - PHP, ASP, Ruby(on Rails), ColdFusion, Python, etc
#4 - MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc
#6 - jQuery, Prototype, etc

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development

Answer (score 3):

Learn as your projects warrant, You can't learn everything so start with what you're being asked to do and branch out when you find things you enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit confused.  Neither jQuery nor "HTML DOM" nor MySQL are languages.  More importantly, there is not really a fixed order, though certain combinations (e.g. HTML + CSS   + JS) are obviously more helpful than others (CSS + SQL).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, first you need to learn HTTP protocol to understand how those things work. Only then you can begin with pure HTML and JavaScript. Then serverside programming: PHP or whatever language you will like.

Frameworks must be learnt AFTER the basic knowledge of those technologies.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what you need to work on. If you are only working on front-end you can will need HTML + CSS + JS. IF you are working on back-end and dynamic page generation you will need to learn a server-side stack (i.e. PHP + MySQL or ASP.NET + SQLServer).

I started from the back-end coding and move through to learning HTML + CSS + JS

Answer (score -3):

You're better off with Python instead of PHP if you want to become a programmer, not just crank out sites badly enough.

What's the point of knowing SQL before server-side programming?
XHTML can be dropped altogether or pushed down.

Comment: This is a fairly ridiculous comment.  PHP is a important web language, albeit a poorly designed one.  SQL is quite useful for certain client-side apps, and ignoring XHTML is stupid.

Comment: Well, it might be important, but if you *start* it as a first language, you'd be SCREWED. Newbies are most sensitive to design quality, they just don't know that and therefore are easy to bullshit.